# Does dropbox provide new account creation via SDK in IOS app?

Tags: iphone, dropbox-api

hi Friends  i have to implement Drop box API in my project. Does Dropbox provide new account creation via SDK in IPHONE application? or Already  signed user only Acces Dropbox through IOS application. Please Help me 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API does not currently offer a call for account creation. Users can create accounts via the Web site or official app if necessary.